# startActivty in a different thread

Tags: android

I'm very very new to android. Hopefully this is not a dumb question.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Question: why does this work? is it normal that startActivity can be called from a secondary thread?

I thought that all UI related things had to be done in the UI thread.

Comment: `.run()` runs the code on the current thread. You should call `.start()` to run it on a new thread. Doesn't answer the question but at least letting you know this isn't a real test of your question.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan You are right, but it was a typo. I meant start(), my bad. I can't accept Doug's answer, need to wait 9 minutes it seems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startActivity` is not immediate.  It schedules the start of the activity to run at the next available cycle on the main thread, so you can call it from anywhere.  (That doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea, though.)

You are not supposed to touch the view hierarchy anywhere except the main thread.  That's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

> `startActivity` method can be called from any `Activity Context`

A new instance of the thread has access to the `Context`, which in turn has an `Activity`. That is why your code is working.

> Note that if this method is being called from outside of an `Activity
>   Context`, then the `Intent` must include the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`
>   launch flag. This is because, without being started from an existing
>   `Activity`, there is no existing task in which to place the new activity
>   and thus it needs to be placed in its own separate task.

This method throws `ActivityNotFoundException` if there was no `Activity` found to run the given Intent.

For more info, read [this developer manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent))